# What quantities are Lorenz-Invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, invariants, big-list

I understand that quantities in physics can either be Lorenz-Invariant (eg charge) or Lorenz-Covariant (eg length).  Is it possible to obtain an exhaustive list of which quantities are which?

Comment: There is no "either or."  also variables may not obey Lorenz transformations at all, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/ltrans.html . Theories may or may not be Lorenz invariant too. https://cds.cern.ch/record/2674125/files/337.pdf

Comment: Not sure whether length is covariant. It is a three-dimensional quantity, to make it make sense in spacetime you have to provide additional information (how you would measure it), which, IMHO, is not unique. In general,  you can usually figure out covariance from the govenring laws, e.g. from Maxwell's Equations.

Comment: Hi Derek Seabrooke. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If someone gave you a finite list of Lorentz invariants, you could always combine them (for example, by multiplication or division) to create new ones.

Comment: OP didn't ask for a *finite* list though. It's like asking "what are the even integers" and you would answer: "you cannot write down a list because the sum of two even integers is also an even integer". While true, you can also write down an infinite list in finitely many symbols, in this case $2\mathbb N$. (The question is still terrible, but for different reasons).